# I don't understand why DbSet<>.OfType<> Throws not valid metadata type for filter operations

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have the following uninformative (in my opinion) error message:

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
>
> Message='Company.Data.DataProvider.Schema.DerivedType' is not a valid metadata type for type filtering operations. Type filtering is only valid on entity types and complex types.

I have the following Tables in my database:

```
BaseType
ObjectID uniqueidentifier
.. other unrelated columns

DerivedType
ObjectID unqueidentifier
UserID unqueidentifier
.. other unrelated columns
```

I have the following classes used by Entity Framework using Inheritance:

```
BaseType
Guid ObjectID 
.. other unrelated properties

DerivedType : BaseType
Guid UserID 
.. other unrelated properties
```

My Partial SchemaContext looks like:

```
public partial class SchemaContext
{
  public IQueryable<DerivedType> DerivedTypes
  {
    get { return this.BaseType.OfType<DerivedType>()
  }
}
```

I have a method that looks like:

```
result = this._dbContexts.SchemaContext.DerivedTypes
  .Include(i => i.RatingType)
  .Include(i => i.ObjectVersion)
  .Where(dt => objectIDs.Any(id => 
                 dt.ObjectVersion.
                   .MatchingObjects
                   .Select(s => s.ObjectID).Contains(id))
               && dt.UserID == userID)
  .ToList();
```

I believe the `.OfType<>` is throwing the error, and I cannot use the base type because I need to filter on the UserID.  Any suggestions on solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this error message is indicationg that your derived type is not properly defined in the Entity Model. If using a POCO/Context generator that manipulates entity object type names, verify that the name of your objects matches.

Comment: It appears when I re-added my `DerivedType` to the edmx I didn't name it exactly the name, so it didn't have any metadata type for type filtering or any other methods.